# Keeping object on the screen

Tags: object, collision-detection, processing

Now I'm sure you all are over hearing about these stupid billiard game questions and this should hopefully be my last, I've got the collision down but keeping it the ball on the screen is a bit of the problem. How do I go about doing that?

```
 class Ball {
  int xpos, ypos;
  int ballDiam;
  color myColor;
  Ball(int tempdiam, color tempColor) {
    ballDiam=tempdiam;
    myColor=tempColor;
  }

  void update() {
    fill(myColor);
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, ballDiam, ballDiam);
  }
}

Ball b1, b2;
int click;
String msg;
int steps = 30;
int difx,dify;
Boolean moving = false;
void setup() {
  msg="";
  click=0;
  size(600, 300);
  b2= new Ball(50, #000000);
  b1 = new Ball(50, #ffffff);
}
void draw() {
  background(#009900);
  b1.update();
  b2.update();

  if (click==0) {
    b1.xpos=mouseX;
    b1.ypos=mouseY;

    msg="click to place ball";
  }
  if (click==0) {
    b1.xpos=mouseX;
    b1.ypos=mouseY;
    b1.update();
  }
  else if (click==1) {
    b2.xpos=mouseX;
    b2.ypos=mouseY;
    b2.update();
    difx = b1.xpos-b2.xpos;
    dify = b1.ypos-b2.ypos;
    msg="click to place eightball and shoot";
  } else if(click==2){
    b1.xpos-=difx/steps;
    b1.ypos-=dify/steps;
    b1.update();
    //cdistance = dist(b1.xpos,b1.ypos,b2.xpos,b2.ypos);
    float distance = dist(b1.xpos,b1.ypos,b2.xpos,b2.ypos);
    if(distance>b2.ballDiam/2){
      moving = true;
      b1.xpos-=difx/steps;
      b1.ypos-=dify/steps;
    }
    else{
      moving = false;
      msg="new";
      click=3;

    }

  }

  else if(click==3){
    if (b1.xpos<b2.xpos && b1.ypos<b2.ypos){
        b2.xpos+=5;
        b2.ypos+=5;
      }
    if (b1.xpos>b2.xpos && b1.ypos>b2.ypos){
        b2.xpos-=5;
        b2.ypos-=5;
      }
    if (b1.xpos>b2.xpos && b1.ypos<b2.ypos){
        b2.xpos-=5;
        b2.ypos+=5;
      }
    if (b1.xpos<b2.xpos && b1.ypos>b2.ypos){
        b2.xpos+=5;
        b2.ypos-=5;
      }
    msg="click again to start over";
  }
 else if(click==4){
   setup();
 }


  textSize(20);
  text(msg, 0, height-5);
}


void mouseClicked() {
  if(!moving){
    click++;
  }
}
```

Comment: what language are you working in?

Comment: I'm using the program processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is almost the same way that you are doing your collision detection between the two balls, expect you need to test between the ball and the bounds of your screen... 
You also want to make sure to utilize the diameter property of your Ball class to make sure you really get the edge of the ball and it doesn't half bounce out and come back in...

```
if( b1.xpos + b1.ballDiam >= width ) { // middle of the ball plus its diameter is over the right screen bounds
  println("ball hit the right side");
  b1.xpos = width - b1.ballDiam; // clamping the position to the bounds of the screen
  b1.reverse(); // you probably want to do something about making it bounce back at this point
}

if( b1.xpos - b1.ballDiam <= 0 ) { // middle of the ball minus its parameter is over the left screen bounds
  println("ball hit the left side");
  // all the other stuff here
}

if( b1.ypos - b1.ballDiam <= 0 ) { // middle of the ball minus its parameter is over the top screen bounds
  println("ball hit the top side");
  // all the other stuff here
}

if( b1.ypos + b1.ballDiam >= height ) { // middle of the ball minus its parameter is over the bottom screen bounds
  println("ball hit the bottom side");
  // all the other stuff here
}
```

Make sense ?